# Android - In Fragment Text look a lot smaller. Tiny tiny ... tiny

Tags: android, fragment

No really, I haven't done anything specific.
I was following this tuto : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

I'm just loading my fragment with replace from FragmentManager.

I tried to change textSize in Fragment's Layout.
I tried on other devices, other rom...
I tried lauching him in a FrameLayout or LinearLayout...

There is nothing to do :>

I'm sure you have used Fragment. And I'm sure it happened to you ! Tell me. Tell me what I need to know :)

As Random Data, here is :

My fragment's layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_margin="3dp">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_margin="7dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BillId"
                android:text="BillId : "
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BuyerLastName"
                android:text="BuyerLastName : "
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BuyerFirstName"
                android:text="BuyerFirstName : "
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/CarId"
                android:text="CarId : "
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_margin="7dp"
                  android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BillIdValue"
                android:text="BillId"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BuyerLastNameValue"
                android:text="BuyerLastName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/BuyerFirstNameValue"
                android:text="BuyerFirstName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/CarIdValue"
            android:text="CarId"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my fragment Java Code :

```
public class ShowCarFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_show_car, container, false);

    }
}
```

And here I launch the fragment in my Activity :

```
if (getMaxPayne() >= 2) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new ShowCarFragment())
                        .commit();
            } else {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, new ShowCarFragment())
                        .commit();
            }
```

**Thank you dear Fragment Master. May Mickey's Force be with you :)**

Comment: Are you sure this issue is limited to your fragment?

Make sure you specify the textSize for you TextViews. Try something like 24sp or 36sp for larger text.

Comment: Yes, I tried to give different textSize to the TxtVw. One is 36sp, an other is 24 etc etc ... And it looks like the default textSize in a fragment is of 14sp.

Comment: Is any theme being applied? Possibly in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: No theme is applied. No style neither. Should I apply some ?